# Wait for Volley to return an answer to update adapter

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am having trouble waiting for Volley's response before updating my RecyclerView's adapter. I am aware of the `OnResponse` method that the Request has, however, I have no way to pass the adapter as a parameter to it. Is there an easy way no notify my adapter that Volley has provided an answer?

```
private static JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, espUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        if (espVideos != null) {
                            espVideos.clear();
                        }
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contentDetails").getString("videoId");
                            String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                            espVideo = new YTVideo(id, title);
                            espVideos.add(espVideo);
                        }
                        SaveObject.saveYTVArray("espVideos", espVideos);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
});

public static void requestEspeciales(Activity act, ImageAdapterEspeciales adapter) {
    Volley.newRequestQueue(act).add(jsonReq);
    // I WANT TO CALL adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); AFTER RESPONSE
}
```

EDIT:

I tried with a synchronize call but the page just freezes `onCreate`

```
synchronized (jsonReq) {
    try {
        jsonReq.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
    Log.d("Notifying", espVideo.toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    synchronized (jsonReq) {
        try {
            if (espVideos != null) {
                espVideos.clear();
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contentDetails").getString("videoId");
                String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                String description = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("description");
                String thumbnailPath = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("high").getString("url");
                String correspondingPlaylist = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("playlistId");

                espVideo = new YTVideo(id, title, description, thumbnailPath, correspondingPlaylist);
                espVideos.add(espVideo);
            }
            SaveAndRetrieve.saveYTVArray("espVideos", espVideos);
            Log.d("Retrieving", ((YTVideo) SaveAndRetrieve.getYTVArray("espVideos").get(0)).title);
            notify();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add it after the for loop -- try that --  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { .... } adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); --- make sure your adapter is public   --- public MyAdapter adapter;   -- just after --- public class MyActivity extends ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no way to pass the adapter as a parameter to it.

You actually have two ways.

1. make the Adapter a `final` parameter of a method surrounding the Volley request. In other words, move the request from a static field and into a method.
2. More preferred, make the Adapter a member variable of the class

Both ways allow you to reference the adapter from within the onResponse method

Answer (score 1):

Just set your recycler adapter inside your  volleyresponse

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    synchronized (jsonReq) {
        try {
            if (espVideos != null) {
                espVideos.clear();
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contentDetails").getString("videoId");
                String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                String description = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("description");
                String thumbnailPath = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("high").getString("url");
                String correspondingPlaylist = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("playlistId");      

                espVideo = new YTVideo(id, title, description, thumbnailPath, correspondingPlaylist);
                espVideos.add(espVideo);
            }
            SaveAndRetrieve.saveYTVArray("espVideos", espVideos);
            Log.d("Retrieving", ((YTVideo) SaveAndRetrieve.getYTVArray("espVideos").get(0)).title);

            **YourAdapaterClass mAdapter = new YourAdapaterClass(youradapterdata);
            recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);**             
            notify();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```